# simple AES crypter test (ECB)

Tags: c, linux, encryption, cryptography, kernel-module

Below kernel module is supposed to encrypt a single block of data with ecb(aes). It seems that "crypto_blkcipher_encrypt" function does not write to output buffer. What am I doing wrong in this module? I search a lot in Google and in here. I also read kernel documentation but I can not find any good answer.

kernel version 2.6.34.1

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/errno.h>
#include <linux/crypto.h>
#include <linux/scatterlist.h>
#include <linux/vmalloc.h>

void my_test(void)
{
   uint32_t *input;
   uint32_t *output;
   uint32_t *temp;
   unsigned char *src;
   unsigned char *dst;
   size_t blk_len=16;
   size_t key_len=16;
   int ret;

   struct crypto_blkcipher *my_tfm;
   struct blkcipher_desc desc;
   struct scatterlist *src_sg;
   struct scatterlist *dst_sg;

   unsigned char my_key[32] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                               0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

   unsigned char *my_iv;
   void *iv;
   size_t ivsize=16;
   my_iv = vmalloc(blk_len);
   memset(my_iv, 0, blk_len);

   temp = vmalloc(blk_len);

   src_sg = vmalloc(sizeof(struct scatterlist));
   if (!src_sg)
   {
      printk("MY_TEST: failed to alloc src_sg!!!\n");
      goto src_sg_free;
   }
   dst_sg = vmalloc(sizeof(struct scatterlist));
   if (!dst_sg)
   {
      printk("MY_TEST: failed to alloc dst_sg!!!\n");
      goto dst_sg_free;
   }
   input = vmalloc(blk_len);
   if (!input)
   {
      printk("MY_TEST: failed to alloc input!!!\n");
      goto input_free;
   }
   output = vmalloc(blk_len);
   if (!output)
   {
      printk("MY_TEST: failed to alloc output!!!\n");
      goto output_free;
   }
   src = vmalloc(blk_len);
   if (!src)
   {
      printk("MY_TEST: failed to alloc src!!!\n");
      goto src_free;
   }
   dst = vmalloc(blk_len);
   if (!dst)
   {
      printk("MY_TEST: failed to alloc dst!!!\n");
      goto dst_free;
   }

   my_tfm = crypto_alloc_blkcipher("ecb(aes)", 0, 0);
   if (!my_tfm)
   {
      printk("MY_TEST: failed to alloc tfm!!!\n");
      goto crypto_free;
   }


   desc.tfm = my_tfm;
   desc.flags = 0;
   crypto_blkcipher_setkey(my_tfm, my_key, key_len);



   iv = crypto_blkcipher_crt(my_tfm)->iv;
   ivsize = crypto_blkcipher_ivsize(my_tfm);

   memcpy(iv, my_iv, ivsize);


   input[0]=0x80000000;
   input[1]=0x00000000;
   input[2]=0x00000000;
   input[3]=0x00000000;
   printk("MY_TEST: input: %x,%x,%x,%x\n",input[0],input[1],input[2],input[3]);

   *((uint32_t *)(&src[ 0])) = input[0];
   *((uint32_t *)(&src[ 4])) = input[1];
   *((uint32_t *)(&src[ 8])) = input[2];
   *((uint32_t *)(&src[12])) = input[3];

   temp[0]=0xFFFFFFFF;
   temp[1]=0xFFFFFFFF;
   temp[2]=0xFFFFFFFF;
   temp[3]=0xFFFFFFFF;
   *((uint32_t *)(&dst[ 0])) = temp[0];
   *((uint32_t *)(&dst[ 4])) = temp[1];
   *((uint32_t *)(&dst[ 8])) = temp[2];
   *((uint32_t *)(&dst[12])) = temp[3];

   sg_init_one(src_sg, src, blk_len);
   sg_init_one(dst_sg, dst, blk_len);

   ret = crypto_blkcipher_encrypt(&desc, dst_sg, src_sg, src_sg->length);
   if (ret < 0)
      pr_err("MY_TEST: phase one failed %d\n", ret);
   output[0] = *((uint32_t *)(&dst[ 0]));
   output[1] = *((uint32_t *)(&dst[ 4]));
   output[2] = *((uint32_t *)(&dst[ 8]));
   output[3] = *((uint32_t *)(&dst[12]));

   printk("MY_TEST: output: %x,%x,%x,%x\n", output[0], output[1], output[2], output[3]);

   crypto_free_blkcipher(my_tfm);

   vfree(temp);


crypto_free:
   vfree(dst);
dst_free:
   vfree(src);
src_free:
   vfree(output);
output_free:
   vfree(input);
input_free:
   vfree(dst_sg);
dst_sg_free:
   vfree(src_sg);
src_sg_free:
   printk("MY_TEST: END!!!\n");
}




static int test_mod_init(void)
{
   printk("MY_TEST: init.\n");
   my_test();
   return 0;
}

static void test_mod_exit(void)
{
   printk("MY_TEST: exit.\n");

}
module_init(test_mod_init);
module_exit(test_mod_exit);

MODULE_AUTHOR("A.MAS");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("my test module");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

here is part of kernel log:

```
[  335.770838] MY_TEST: init.
[  335.860494] MY_TEST: input: 80000000,0,0,0
[  335.864738] MY_TEST: output: ffffffff,ffffffff,ffffffff,ffffffff
[  335.865459] MY_TEST: END!!!
[  342.484247] MY_TEST: exit.
```

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://wbsun.blogspot.com/2011/01/use-kernel-crypto-lib.html)?

Comment: yes, I had seen it before I wrote the module.